# ReSharper 4.5 took away all intellisense for VS 2008!

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper, intellisense

I just recently purchased ReSharper 4.5 to use with Visual Studio 2008.  Upon installing it, I have noticed that there is no intellisense at all!  There is no ReSharper intellisense, no VS intellisense, nothing).  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the setting in R# Options / IntelliSense / General ?

Comment: I have it currently set as the default (ReSharper).  I have switched it, but have gotten no results.

Comment: I don't know why, but after turning off the Add via the Add-In Manager and then turning it back on, it seems to work now.  I have given Michael Hedgpeth, Garry Shutler, and Jhonny D. Cano -Leftware each a point.  I can't really give one of you the accepted answer, but I hope a point will do.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Resharper -> Options -> Intellisense -> General and make sure something is selected.  Also check over the Completion Behavior and Completion Appearance sections to make sure they match your expectations.

I'm using 4.5 and it works for me, but with a new install you should review the options.

Answer (score 3):

In the Resharper->Options There is a config: IntelliSense/General In which you can choose whethere to use Intellisense features from ReSharper or from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

First thing I'd try would be reinstalling Resharper.

Are you getting any of the Resharper prompts or is it just Intellisense that's messed up?